# Application wide number formats?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, number-formatting

I've got an application with a fairly large amount (and variety) of swing components. Anyone know if there's a way to set a consistent NumberFormat across all of these components (perhaps via the UIManager?), or am I going to have to extend each component into a custom one with references to a static NumberFormat object?

Thanks!

Comment: You might use a factory method to stamp out the components.

Comment: `NumberFormat` has some standard factories.

Comment: Can you post an example of the refactoring needed?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
code
call=> formatNumber(yourNumber);
code
private String formatNumber(String value) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();        
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while(m.find()) {
    String g = m.group();
    m.appendReplacement(sb, nf.format(Double.parseDouble(g)));            
  }
  return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
    }
```